# Библиотека документов Sharepoint

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

Доброго времени суток!
Подскажите, как получить весь список файлов и папок содержащихся в библиотеке?
Не могу разобраться, почему то функция выводит не все каталоги в папке, так же есть еще дублирующие каталоги.

```
    function getfolder(){
var url1, url, title, sub,itemID, upr, otd,zgd, lnk,zgd1, upr1, otd1;
var i=1;
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "my list",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><FieldRef Name='FileRef' /><FieldRef Name='ServerUrl' /></ViewFields>",                
        CAMLQueryOptions: "<QueryOptions><ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll'/></QueryOptions>",
            completefunc: function (xData, status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                  url1 =  $(this).attr("ows_FileRef").split("/"); //papka ЗГД  и все вложения

            if (url1.length>4) {

                          sub =  $(this).attr("ows_FileLeafRef").split(";#")[1]; //file
                          zgd =  $(this).attr("ows_FileRef").split("/")[1];      //papka ЗГД
                          upr =  $(this).attr("ows_FileRef").split("/")[2];      //papka управления
                          otd =  $(this).attr("ows_FileRef").split("/")[3];      //papka отделы
                          lnk =  $(this).attr("ows_ServerUrl");                  //ссылка на файл

                   if (zgd != zgd1){
                     $('#treetbl tbody').append('<tr class="one"><td colspan="4" ><img src="/_layouts/images/folder.gif"/>'+zgd+'</td></tr>');//</tr>
                     zgd1=zgd
                   }
                   if (upr != upr1){
                        $('#treetbl tbody').append('<tr zgd="'+zgd+'" class="two hide" ><td class="tst" colspan="4"><img src="/_layouts/images/folder.gif"/>'+upr+'</td></tr>');
                        //folderName=$(this).attr("ows_FileRef").split("/")[0]+"/"+$(this).attr("ows_FileRef").split("/")[1]+"/"+$(this).attr("ows_FileRef").split("/")[2]+"/";
                        //subfolder(folderName.split(';#')[1], upr);
                        upr1=upr
                   }
                   if (otd != otd1){
                     $('#treetbl tbody').append('<tr upr="'+upr+'" class="three hide" ><td colspan="4"><img src="/_layouts/images/folder.gif"/>'+otd+'</td></tr>');
                        folderName=$(this).attr("ows_FileRef").split("/")[0]+"/"+$(this).attr("ows_FileRef").split("/")[1]+"/"+$(this).attr("ows_FileRef").split("/")[2]+"/";
                        //var tmp=folderName.split(';#');

                        //alert(folderName.split('/')[]);
                        subfolder(folderName.split(';#')[1], upr);
                     otd1=otd
                  //   alert(lnk);
                   }
                    $('#treetbl tbody').append('<tr  otd="'+otd+'" class="hide files"><td colspan="4" ><a href="'+lnk+'" target="_blank">'+sub+'</a></td></tr>');   

                }
            });
        } //complete
    }); //SP
};
```

Comment: SPServices используете потому что все на 2007 версии крутится?

Comment: Вам не надо использовать SPServices, используйте вариант по ссылке:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115980/how-to-get-all-the-files-inside-the-folder-in-list